# Building URL using Uri.builder

Tags: java, android, url

this is the **URL** that I want to build :
**https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185//nrsx0jEaBgXq4PWo7SooSnYJTv.jpg**

```
 public static URL buildImageURL(String query){
    final String Image_Base_URL="image.tmdb.org";
    final String File_Size="w185";

    Uri.Builder builtUri = new Uri.Builder();
    builtUri.scheme("https")
            .authority(Image_Base_URL)
            .appendPath("t")
            .appendPath("p")
            .appendPath(File_Size).appendPath(query).build();
    URL url = null;
    try{
        url = new URL(builtUri.toString());
    }catch (MalformedURLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
return url;
}
```

I can't append **//** in the URL...

Answer (score 0):

If you know your url and need a Uri, use

```
Uri uri =  Uri.parse( "http://www.facebook.com" );
```

If you want to compose the Uri, and get the correct Url, use like this:

```
final static String Image_Base_URL="image.tmdb.org";
private static final String File_Size="w185";

public static String buildImageURL(String query){
    // https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185//nrsx0jEaBgXq4PWo7SooSnYJTv.jpg
    String image = "nrsx0jEaBgXq4PWo7SooSnYJTv.jpg";

    Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
    builder.scheme("https")
            .authority(Image_Base_URL)
            .appendPath("t")
            .appendPath("p")
            .appendPath(File_Size)
            .appendPath(image);
    String myUrl = builder.build().toString();

    return myUrl;
}
```

I have modified your code, and tested. Now it outputs the correct formatted 
URL as string. You can get the URL by using

```
URL myURL = new URL(urlString);
```

The output is:  `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/nrsx0jEaBgXq4PWo7SooSnYJTv.jpg`

Comment: look at the code after editing please..
the buildImageURL method returns the url like this : http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/%2FkY2c7wKgOfQjvbqe7yVzLTYkxJO.jpg

Comment: @Abdelrahman001 Take a look now at my edited answer. It should work.

Comment: Also it returns the same result the problem is the second "/" after file size it turns into encoded characters "%2F"

Comment: I have compiled the code I wrote above. The output is: 
 https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/nrsx0jEaBgXq4PWo7SooSnYJTv.jpg There is no second "/"

Comment: the value of image variable that i receive  from the API contains "\"

Comment: Ok. If you need help, please provide the entire scenario, and describe your problem the best as you can. I wasted some of my time for you to tell me now that the problem is not building the URL? Or..?

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time but I am new at android so I apologize ..
look at the code after editing

Comment: And, just to be sure.. you want to append "//" like here: "rg/t/p/w185//nrsx0jEaBgXq4PWo7SooSnYJTv.jpg"?